# Clicking on a block and controlling a child

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Tell me how to change properties in a child element when clicking on a block

```
!!post &&  post.map((item) =>
    <div key={item.id} onClick={(e)=>onVideo(e)}>
        <video width="310.44" height="458" style={{objectFit: 'cover'}} controls={false}>
            <source src={item.url} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div>
            <div style={{fontSize: '16px'}}>{item.date}</div>
            <div style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',fontSize: '22px'}}>{item.name}</div>
        </div>
    </div>)
```

I need when clicking onVideo an action was applied over the html video full screen was applied and play

Blocks are formed and displayed depending on the number of posts in the post and there may be 10 examples of such blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear to me. If you want to change some prop in video through `onClick` of the div, you need to set up for that. For example, if you want to change the `control` prop on video, through div `onClick`, give `control` a variable, then change the value on div `onClick`. For that case, it would be like this-->

```
const [state,setState] = useState({})
!!post &&  post.map((item) =>
    <div key={item.id} onClick={()=>setState(data=>{...data,{[item.id]:true})}>
        <video width="310.44" height="458" style={{objectFit: 'cover'}} controls={state[item.id]}>
            <source src={item.url} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div>
            <div style={{fontSize: '16px'}}>{item.date}</div>
            <div style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',fontSize: '22px'}}>{item.name}</div>
        </div>
    </div>)
```

Comment: When you click on the div block, you need to be able to change the video block.
Example when clicking on the onVideo block, change the video's controls value

Comment: All in all there is a solution in your answer. Just add useState to the map and it will solve my question

Comment: My bad. useState needs to be initialized outside the map. Edited

Comment: thanks for your answer, just a question to improve, what do you do in case of an empty array  **post** ?

Comment: Then the question remains if fails to initialize in map

I was thinking to add const useRef = useRef (); in the map and already navigate by it

Data comes from the database, I output them N number, these are videos, I need to work with them. Namely, with a video, so that I could refer to it depending on which one I clicked on them

Comment: Edited. Try this, should work